# Choosing every other column of a data table in R. What is the difference between two syntaxes

Tags: r, data.table

Lets create data table, `data_1`. I would like to choose every other column, lets say the odd columns.  What is the difference between the following two syntaxes? Why the second one does not work?

```
data_1 = data.table(col_1 = c(11, 21, 31),
                    col_2 = c(12, 22, 32),
                    col_3 = c(13, 23, 33),
                    col_4 = c(14, 24, 34))

col_dim <- ncol(data_1)
col_dim/2 # this equals 2


odd_cols <- data_1[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 2))] # works
odd_cols

   col_1 col_3
1:    11    13
2:    21    23
3:    31    33

odd_cols <- data_1[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), (col_dim/2)))] # does not work!
odd_cols
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use `with = FALSE` with `data.table`.  It gives the same output in both datasets.   According to `?data.table`

> with - By default with=TRUE and j is evaluated within the frame of x; column names can be used as variables. In case of overlapping variables names inside dataset and in parent scope you can use double dot prefix ..cols to explicitly refer to 'cols variable parent scope and not from your datase

```
out1 <- data_1[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), (col_dim/2))), with = FALSE]
out2 <- data_1[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 2)), with = FALSE]
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

If we check with `verbose = TRUE`

```
data_1[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), (col_dim/2))), verbose = TRUE]
#Detected that j uses these columns: <none> 
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

while in the first case, it was treated as the `j` index directly

```
data_1[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 2)), verbose = TRUE]
#    col_1 col_3
#1:    11    13
#2:    21    23
#3:    31    33
```

In the first case, we are providing a numeric/integer value, while in the second case, it is also trying to find the object  (`col_dim`) in the global environment.  Just to understand, the behavior, done some experiments

1) providing the value of 'col_dim' and then do the division with 2

```
data_1[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 4/2))]
#  col_1 col_3
#1:    11    13
#2:    21    23
#3:    31    33
```

2) to rule out the type

```
n1 <- 2L
data_1[, c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), n1))]
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

So, it might be the evaluation of global object that changes the behavior

Comment: what does `with = FALSE` do? why it did not work without it?
How did you change your user name ? :D

Comment: @NoLie  Updated with the description from `?data.table`.  Regarding the 3rd question, I didn't get it.  My username is the same as earlier